# Unable to resolve module `react-native-reanimated`

Tags: react-native

React native project running fine without react navigation tab module, once I installed the tab module using

> `npm install --save react-navigation-tab`

The following error occure on node terminal.

React-tab-navigation throwing the following error.

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-reanimated` from `node_modules\react-navigation-tabs\lib\module\views\MaterialTopTabBar.js`: react-native-reanimated could not be found within the project.

Comment: I get the same error right now! But I guess is react-navigation-tabs, try again!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

react-navigation-tabs depends on react-navigation package.
So I think you missed the [Getting Started](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) section.

Currently for react-navigation 4.x you should:

```
yarn add react-navigation
yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens@^1.0.0-alpha.23
```

Then for ios:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

To finalize installation of react-native-screens for Android, add the following two lines to dependencies section in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

And then

```
react-native link react-native-reanimated
```

Answer (score 20):

## If you are working with Expo

I had the exact same problem this is what I did and it worked!!

#### Follow the Getting started guide

This is basically install the required dependencies for react Navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

`yarn add @react-navigation/native`

and

`expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

Then I realized that `react-native-reanimated` was within the unmet peer dependencies, so to ensure that the proper version is installed you have to run `expo install react-native-reanimated`

[image: yarn warning]

try again and that's it!!

pdta...

I figured out this because I deleted the node_modules folder and installed again all the dependencies by `yarn install` so, if have a problem this would be the desperate last try. though I dont think this will be necesary.

Comment: I had to do `yarn cache clean` as well (after removing node modules)

Comment: this worked for me today. had to have version "react-native-reanimated": "3.3.0" along with the other installs he noted above. then ran expo r -c to clear cache and restart terminal and run expo-cli start --tunnel and im good

Answer (score 9):

I'm using react-native 0.67 version

I follow the following step to fix it

step 1. npm i react-native-reanimated

step 2. add plugin
babel.config.js

```
plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
```

step 3 When trying to run the code after close the terminal I still I'm facing same issue

```
Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?
```

step 4.
After that, i close the current terminal and run this command

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

now issue in fixed.

Comment: it works! I am using react-native-router-flux

Comment: for expo managed projects run expo r -c

Answer (score 4):

### React Native CLI

I had experienced the same issue with  **`react-native: "^0.64.0"`** and react-navigation **`5.x`**

I had followed the installation on the  [React Navigation Getting Started](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started). I started out using **`createStackNavigator`** and **`createBottomTabNavigator`** and my builds we working fine.

As soon as I added **`createDrawerNavigator`** my builds were failing with errors:

> *Unable to resolve module `react-native-reanimated`*
>
> **and/or**
>
> *Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(…): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found*

### Dependencies

Installation of React Navigation

> npm install @react-navigation/native

Installing dependencies

> yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler
> react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
> @react-native-community/masked-view

### Reason for Issue

Reanimated dependency `"react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0"` as stated in the official documentation requires some additional configs, including ***babel***, ***Hermes***, and ***MainApplication.java*** to work properly with React Native.

I guess Reanimated **`^2.0.0`** is not yet supported on React Native **`^0.64.0`**

Check the solution below or follow the official documentation to resolve [React Native Reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation)

> requires additional steps apart from just adding a dependency to
> package.json

### Solution

NOTE: After making changes make sure to clear `gradle` and `yarn` caches

Three changes needs to be made

1. Add Reanimated's babel plugin to your `babel.config.js`

> ```
>   module.exports = {
>       ...
>       plugins: [
>           ...
>           'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
>       ],
>   };
> ```

2. Turn on Hermes engine by editing `android/app/build.gradle`

> ```
> project.ext.react = [
>   enableHermes: true  // <- here | clean and rebuild if changing
> ]
> ```

3. Plug Reanimated in `MainApplication.java`

> ```
>   import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage; // <- add
>   import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage; // <- add
>   ...
>   private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
>   ...
>
>       @Override
>       protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
>         return "index";
>       }
>
>       @Override
>       protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
>         return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); // <- add
>       }
>     };
>   ...
> ```

---

Comment: Please provide some more explanation on the answer and the documentation which can easily help others as well.

Comment: @VivekSingh sure, I had made updates to clarify my answer and the documentation. Out of curiosity though you could have just skipped my shallow answer, why then ask that I explain a bit further? I am a new contributor I would be happy to hear what you have to say ...

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error and this is how I went about fixing it:

1. Download [react native project](https://github.com/software-mansion-labs/reanimated-2-playground) from github
2. Run the following command:

```
npm install
react-native start
react-native run-android
```

Then build your app.

3. When it completes the build, move your required profile jects and install your required npm packages.
4. Run the following commands:

```
npm cache clean --force
cd android
gradlew clean
gradle cleanBuildCache
gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
cd ..
npx react-native start --reset-cache
npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 3):

`npx react-native-clean-project` have solved my problems

Comment: This seems like it did it for me after trying everything else and failing.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it worked

1: Install it

```
npx expo install react-native-reanimated
```

2: add in babel.config.js

```
plugins: [
      [
          'module-resolver',
          {
              alias: {
                  '@': './src',
                  'assets': './assets',
              }
          },
      ],
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
   ],
```

3: run again

```
npx start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 2):

Reanimated Version: 2.0.0

Downgrade to 1.13.2 solved the problem, unfortnutely

Answer (score 1):

Install `**react-native-reanimated**` library

> npm i react-native-reanimated

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is able to uninstall react-native-reanimated without issues to their application, all I had to do was uninstall the current react-native-reanimated with(from the node_modules folder):

```
npm uninstall react-native-reanimated
```

I then ran

```
npm install react-navigation-tabs --save
```

Reload and problem solved for me.

Similar to the reinstall a lower version except this way react-navigation-tabs will install the one it wants.

Comment: This was by far the simplest solution for me. I was getting my issue when it came to `import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";`

Answer (score 1):

Currently for **react-navigation@6.x**, you should install **react-native-gesture-handler** and **react-native-reanimated.**

If you have an Expo managed project, in your project directory, run:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

If you have a bare React Native project, in your project directory, run:

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

important:
To finalize the installation of react-native-gesture-handler, add the following at the top (**make sure it's at the top and there's nothing else before it**) of your entry file, such as index.js or App.js:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to reset your bundler's cache (yarn start --reset-cache or npm start -- --reset-cache).

Answer (score 0):

Reanimated v2 only supports react-native 0.62+

So if you are using a lower version downgrade version as @mehmet-emin-sayım said - Downgrade to 1.13.2 solved the problem

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the mentioned steps in Reanimated Documentation Installation but it was not working for me.

1:  I add the following code in my babel.config.js because I am using React-Native CLI

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

//...........OR..........(You can add any)

```
 module.exports = function (api) {
      api.cache(true);
      return {
        presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
        plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
      };
    };
```

2:  After that, I added this line at the top of my App.js:

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

3:  Reset the cache:

npx react-native start --reset-cache

Answer (score 0):

For **Expo Web**, there is an extra step to fix this error message.

> Reanimated for Web requires the following configuration steps. You need to add `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from` as well as Reanimated Babel plugin to your `babel.config.js`.
>
> **Source**: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/web-support

```
$ yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from
```

```
// babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
      ...
  ],
  plugins: [
    ...
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from', 
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

At the end, clear the expo web cache and restart the project.

```
$ rm -rf .expo/web/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade reanimated from version 3.5.4 to v3.3.0 worked for me:

```
npm install react-native-reanimated@3.3.0
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because react-native-reanimated.

Just use

```
npm i react-native-reanimated@1
```

it will download react-native-reanimated: "^1.13.3" which is competitive to react-navigation-tab.

Then use

```
npm install --save react-navigation-tab
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, this was fixed by running

```
npm uninstall react-native-reanimated
npm install react-native-reanimated
```

For Expo users: I am intentionally avoiding `expo install react-native-reanimated` here.

Comment: not worked for me