# The development server returned response error code: 500 URL: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Tags: react-native

How can I solve it. Where do you think the error

The development server returned response error code: 500 URL: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

[image: 500 error server react-native]

**metro**

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli start
(node:34741) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   /Users/mbp/Documents/erkan/TurRota 

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `module:react-native-reanimated.Animated.log` from `src/components/Mainpage/Mapview.js`: module:react-native-reanimated.Animated.log could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/mbp/Documents/erkan/TurRota/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/mbp/Documents/erkan/TurRota/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/mbp/Documents/erkan/TurRota/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/mbp/Documents/erkan/TurRota/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at /Users/mbp/Documents/erkan/TurRota/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:426:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/mbp/Documents/erkan/TurRota/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at /Users/mbp/Documents/erkan/TurRota/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/mbp/Documents/erkan/TurRota/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░ 41.6% (620/1016), failed.

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jan/2021:09:43:18 +0000] "GET /index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131602/unable-to-resolve-module-react-native-reanimated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case This is a bug on version 0.56. so, suggest you to downgrade from 0.56 to version 0.55 just run this command

**npm install react-native@0.55.4 --save**