# react-native-reanimated not downloading while building app

Tags: android, react-native

The build process of my app is not completing and it stops at react-native-reanimated setup.

This is my terminal screen

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NVvC.png)

I have tried a few of the commands from a similar stack overflow thread

([Unable to resolve module `react-native-reanimated`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131602/unable-to-resolve-module-react-native-reanimated)) but I think it is a different problem because its not working and the same error persists.

I am an absolute beginner in this field and please let me know if you need any additional info regarding this error like dependencies etc.

My dependencies are
My dependencies are added here

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.3",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "^0.70.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.0",
"react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.4",
"react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.8.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.30.1",
"react-native-share": "^8.0.0"
```

},
Here it shows react-native-reanimated correctly but it it still shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error says that this package `(react-native-reanimated)` is missing. You can install it by using:

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated
```

or:

```
npm install react-native-reanimated
```

For documentation, you can visit [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/#installation).

Answer (score 0):

There is some additional setup for Reanimated.You can follow steps in doc
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/

I think you're missing `babel.config.js` configuration.